# how blur or focus vuejs component based on a vuex state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've got a little problem with vuejs.

My state is basically something like this.

```
  state: ()=>({
        activeSide : "from",
    }),
```

I want a component to be focused or blurred based on whether activeSide has the value activeSide set to "from" or not

my idea at the moment, doesn't seem to be very elegant, I basically created a computed property in my component,

```
focusSide(){
    console.log("changed active side")
    this.$store.state.activeSide
}
```

and then I set up a watch to see if that property changes.

```
watch:{
focusSide : function(newV,_){
  console.log("changing focus")
  newV=="from" ? this.$refs.fromArea.$el.focus() : this.$refs.fromArea.blur()
}
```

},

the problems here is that apart from the fact that the solution doesn't look elegant the watch doesn't work either, I've seen that focusSide is changing its value correctly (or at least the body of the method is executed), but the watcher is not executed, I have the feeling that since focusSide state is never used in my template, vuejs thinks that it's not necessary to react and change values, something like reactive frameworks where if the value is not observated then don't change (maybe I'm wrong)

what would be the ideal way for achieve this???
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need return value of computed properties `focusSide`, otherwise it will always return undefined

```
focusSide () {
    console.log("changed active side")
    return this.$store.state.activeSide
}
```

Comment: thank you @ittus I probably erased this at a time when I was testing different codes. the watcher does not seem to be changing the focus.

I based my code on this
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-set-focus-to-input/10672

but this.$refs.fromArea.$el is undefined, after check the debugger seems that 

      this.$refs.fromArea.focus()

the focus function exist and probably is the right way, but doesn't change the focus in my component.

By the way...do you think this is the best way to do it???
thank you

Comment: check @ittus, works when change the code to  this.$refs.fromArea.focus()  and put the return statement (thank you for notice it)...best regards

Comment: No problem, happy coding!